# Setting a class member var from a dictionary object

Tags: ios5, nsdictionary

Class member var named "id" below is of type int. Need to set from a dictionary object. 
Tried type casting (int)[tip objectForKey:@"id"] did not return the correct integer value. Can someone help?

Thanks

```
        for (NSDictionary *t in tips) {

           //prints 5876 which is correct
            NSLog(@"id: %@",[t objectForKey:@"id"]);

            Tip *myTip = [[Tip alloc] init];

            // returns incorrect integer value
            [myTip setId:(int)[tip objectForKey:@"id"]];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[myTip setId:[[tip objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
```